# Initialize Session bean from request scop bean

Tags: jsf-2

**Hi All**
I am using JSF 2.0 , I have two beans UserBean ( Request Scope ) and UserInfoBean( Session Scope ).
I want to know how can initialize UserInfoBean from one method of UserBean( Request Scope ) so that i can access it from anywhere.

I also want to know performance wise which is better 1. Put a bean as session bean 2. put different different variable in session individually.

**Thanks A Lot**

Answer (score 4):

Inject the session scoped bean as [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) of the request scoped bean. This way it's available to all action methods in the request scoped bean.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager {

    private User user;

    // ...
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Login {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userManager}")
    private UserManager userManager;

    public String submit() {
        User user = userService.find(username, password);

        if (user != null) {
            userManager.setUser(user);
            return "home";
        } else {
            addMessage("Unknown login, try again");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```